# Tile a SECTION of a texture without changing the UV unwrap

Tags: texturing, uv, node-editor, shader-nodes, texture-coordinates

So say I have a texture like this

[image]

And I'd like to tile just one quadrant, like this. Using shader-editor nodes, and not touching the UV editor at all.

[image]

***Without*** going into the UV Editor and changing the way the UV is laid out, how might I go about cropping into a section of a texture, and repeating that section using **ONLY** nodes and nothing else?

I've tried this

[image]
And while it *seems* to do something similar, it's not quite what I'm looking for.
Anybody have anything that should work?

I'm not interested in questions of *why* I'm doing something like this or alternate solutions that don't involve nodes, as I have a very specific use-case and I've tried to simplify the problem as much as possible to make it easier to answer. This is what I need to do in this situation, I'm just looking for how to make it possible.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you need to calculate the modulo using the section dimensions as divisor.
Then, you add the section starting position:

(The values used here are for section A)

[image: Material nodes]

In your case, all sections have the same dimensions: (0.5, 0.5), but have different positions, so position is the only thing you will need to change to display other sections:

[image: Changing current section]

Comment: Yup, this is exactly what I needed. Guess what I had was on the right track, I just wasn't using it correctly, or I had it in the wrong place on my actual setup, since it's a bit of a nightmare.